# an int array from Command Line Arguments

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to convert command line arguments in an int array, but it appears a "0" in the end of the array. How can I fix it?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] game = new int[9];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        game[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(game));
}
```

Example run:

```
$ java edu.kit.informatik.TicTacToe 5 6 4 1 2 3 7 8 9
[5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: Is that really the output from that code? I don't see how a `new int[9]` array with 9 elements could be printed with 10 numbers in it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code, there aren't '0' at the end of the list. I recommend you that use `args.length` for handling variety arguments count.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] game = new int[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            game[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(game));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new `int[]` array in Java, its initial contents are all zeros. If you then fill it up with fewer numbers than it is long, you'll see the zeros that have not been overwritten at the end.

```
// creating an array of size 10
int[] array = new int[10];

// only filling up the first 8 elements
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    array[i-1] = i;
}

// printing the full array
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

This will output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 0
```

The last two zeros are just the elements that have not been set to anything else.